# Check for mandatory fields while saving Sharepoint Item programmatically

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, splist

I have a Mandatory field  in a list. I need to save the item  and not create the item.

I need to implement the it using custom JavaScript and not use the save button on the new form.

Also need to check if the mandatory fields are set and stop the item from being saved and show the validation messages.

The following does save the item  but does not  check if the field is manadatory. It also redirects the page to the edit form as required.

```
$("input[id='DummyButton']").bind("click", function() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    var title = $("input[id^='Title']").val();

    var Teststandard = $("div[id^='testStandard'] p").html();
    oListItem.set_item('Title', title);
    oListItem.set_item('Tenures', tenures);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
        $(location).attr('href',_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl +    '/Lists/test/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + oListItem.get_id() + '&newedit=1'); 
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +'\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
});
```

Is there a way to use the default save  javascript or use the `PreSaveAction()` function?

Comment: Please give me more information 1. Are you creating a custom web part? 2. Can you manage to write server side code for saving the list item and do validations at client side?

Comment: No I am  writing custom JavaScript and adding it to a content  editor web part.